# What is the best way to send messages to Socket.IO clients from various back-ends

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

My Setup:
I have an existing python script that is using Tweepy to access the Twitter Streaming API.  I also have a website that shows aggregate real-time information from other sources from various back-ends.

My Ideal Scenario:
I want to publish real-time tweets as well as real-time updates of my other information to my connected users using Socket.IO.

It would be really nice if I could do something as simple as an HTTP POST (from any back-end) to broadcast information to all the connected clients.

My Problem:
The Socket.IO client implementation is super straight forward... i can handle that.  But I can't figure out if the functionality I'm asking for already exists... and if not, what would be the best way to make it happen?

**[UPDATE]**

My Solution:  I created a project called Pega.IO that does what I was looking for.  Basically, it lets you use Socket.IO (0.8+) as usual, but you can use HTTP POST to send messages to connected users.

It uses the Express web server with a Redis back-end.  Theoretically this should be pretty simple to scale -- I will continue contributing to this project going forward.

[Pega.IO - github](https://github.com/Gootch/pega.io)

To install on Ubuntu, you just run this command:

```
curl http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Gootch/pega.io/install.sh | sh
```

This will create a Pega.IO server that is listening on port 8888.

Once you are up and running, just:

`HTTP POST http://your-server:8888/send`

with data that looks like this:

```
channel=whatever&secretkey=mysecret&message=hello+everyone
```

That's all there is to it.  HTTP POST from any back-end to your Pega.IO server.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found for this sort of thing is using a message broker. Personally, I've used RabbitMQ for this, which seems to meet the requirements mentioned in your comment on the other answer (socket.io 0.7 and scalable). If you use RabbitMQ, I'd recommend the amqp module for node, available through npm, and the Pika module for Python.

An example connector for Python using pika. This example accepts a single json-serialized argument:

```
    def amqp_transmit(message):
        connection = pika.AsyncoreConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=settings.AMQP_SETTINGS['host'],
            port=settings.AMQP_SETTINGS['port'],
            credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(settings.AMQP_SETTINGS['username'],
                    settings.AMQP_SETTINGS['pass'])))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange_name, type='fanout')
        channel.queue_declare(queue=NODE_CHANNEL, auto_delete=True, durable=False, exclusive=False)
        channel.basic_publish(exchange=exchange_name,
                routing_key='',
                body=message,
                properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                        content_type='application/json'),
                )
        print ' [%s] Sent %r' %(exchange_name, message)
        connection.close()
```

Very basic connection code on the node end might look like this:

```
    var connection = amqp.createConnection(
        {host: amqpHost,
        port: amqpPort,
         password: amqpPass});

    function setupAmqpListeners() {
        connection.addListener('ready', amqpReady)
        connection.addListener('close', function() {
            console.log('Uh oh! AMQP connection failed!');
        });
        connection.addListener('error', function(e) {throw e});
    }

    function amqpReady(){
        console.log('Amqp Connection Ready');
        var q, exc;
        q = connection.queue(queueName,
            {autoDelete: true, durable: false, exclusive: false},
            function(){
                console.log('Amqp Connection Established.');
                console.log('Attempting to get an exchange named: '+exchangeName);
                exc = connection.exchange(exchangeName,
                    {type: 'fanout', autoDelete: false},
                    function(exchange) {
                        console.log('Amqp Exchange Found. ['+exchange.name+']');
                        q.bind(exc, '#');
                        console.log('Amqp now totally ready.');
                        q.subscribe(routeAmqp);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }


    routeAmqp = function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            doStuff(msg);
    }
```

Edit: The example above uses a fan-out exchange that does not persist messages. Fan-out exchange is likely going to be your best option since scalability is a concern (ie: you are running more than one box running Node that clients can be connected to).

Comment: It looks like Socket.IO has built-in support for redis -- though I have no idea how one would use it... maybe I'm missing it in the documentation, but I don't see any clear-cut examples of how to scale Socket.IO 0.7+ horizontally

Comment: I guess I got a bit off topic here... the main part of the question I would like answered is to do with setting up Socket.IO to accept HTTP POST requests from any back-end to broadcast messages rather than through a javascript client

Comment: The issue is that http POST requests to individual node boxes is not scalable. This does not work when you need more than a single box running nodejs to properly respond to the requests... Do you want scalable, or do you want a solution that will be guaranteed to never be capable of scaling beyond a single machine running nodejs? If its the latter, you could just use the nodejs module Express (included in a default nodejs install), and the python module urllib. I'd be happy to provide code examples if anything is confusing within their documentation.

Comment: Definitely want it to scale -- I don't think we should have to choose though?  If there was a way to do an HTTP post to a single node box that emulates what would happen when you do a normal emit or broadcast through javascript -- it should hopefully be able to send to clients on all node boxes, shouldn't it?

Comment: You _could_ (although I would strongly recommend against it) use HTTP requests for communicating between node boxes. Message queueing solutions exist specifically to do what you're looking to do, in a scalable fashion. Another alternative that might be more effective than HTTP but less effective than a full MQ solution would be to use https://github.com/remy/Socket.io-node-client and have the Node instances connect to one another with that. (note: I have not used this since socket.io v0.6)

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your Node app so that there are two parts:

1. The Socket.IO portion, which communicates directly with the clients, and
2. An HTTP API of some sort, which receives POST requests and then broadcasts appropriate messages with Socket.IO.

In this way, your application becomes a "bridge" between your non-Node apps and your users' browsers. The key here is to use Socket.IO for what it was made for--real time communication to browsers--and rely on other Node technologies for other parts of your application.

[Update]

I'm not on a development environment at the moment, so I can't get you a working example, but some pseudocode would look something like this:

```
http = require('http');
io   = require('socket.io');

server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  // Parse the HTTP request to get the data you want
  io.sockets.emit("data", whatever); // broadcast the data to Socket.IO clients
});
server.listen(8080);
socket_server = io.listen(server);
```

With this, you'd have a web server on port 8080 that you can use to listen to web requests (you could use a framework such as Express or one of many others to parse the body of the POST request and extract the data you need).

Comment: A recipe for this would be great... it does sound like it would be a good way to do it.  I'm sure there are lots of new node.js folk (including myself) who would learn a lot from an actual implementation example.  A couple things to keep in mind... it needs to scale (redis?) and it needs to use Socket.IO 0.7+ (for the hybi-10 support)